# How can I remove lines from my file according to a threshold in Unix?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an input file with different columns, like the following:

```
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value           
7:106350628_G_A,rs6977865,7,106350628,G,A,-0.0808873,8.6E-309
7:106353698_T_C,rs74804152,7,106353698,T,C,-0.0808701,9.3E-309
20:57674276_T_A,rs6026699,20,57674276,T,A,-0.0945835,6.0E-314
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
2:31467079_G_A,rs2295471,2,31467079,G,A,-0.0830949,8.6E-320
```

Now, I'd like to remove the rows at which the P-value is less than 2.23E-308, in order to have the following output file:

```
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

I ran the following command in the Unix shell:

```
awk -F, '$8!"<2.23E-308"' input.file > output.file
```

However, I still have the first input file, with all the rows...

Is the command wrong? May be there a problem in recognizing the set threshold?

I am using Linux.

Comment: This question is completely on topic and very welcome here, but based on the data you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your expression isn't quite right - it should be

```
a >= b
```

or (if you prefer)

```
!(a < b)
```

rather than `a!"<b"`.

However in your particular case there's a subtler issue that the numerical values are smaller than the smallest value representable as a double precision (64-bit) floating point number.

If you have a version of GNU awk (`gawk`) that is built with the GNU MPFR/MP libraries, you may need to enable arbitrary precision handling via the `-M` or `--bignum` command line options:

```
$ gawk -F, -M '$8 >= 2.23E-308' input.file
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

Otherwise, one possible workaround would be to force numeric conversion before the comparison:

```
$ mawk -F, '$8+0 >= 2.23E-308' input.file
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01

$ awk -F, '$8+0 >= 2.23E-308' input.file
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

but note that this will force values outside the range of a IEEE double to zero (because they're initially converted as strings, and the numerical value of a string is 0).

If you want the header row as well, then add that as a separate logical test:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || $8+0 >= 2.23E-308' input.file
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

Comment: For me, this works out of the box without `-M`: `'$8 >= 2.23E-308'`. (`GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)`

Comment: @pLumo interesting, thanks - I tested this on an older (Ubuntu 18.04) box with gawk 4.1.4 (GNU MP 6.1.2 GNU MPFR 4.0.1) because that's what I happened to have open

Answer (score 8):

Here we break apart the scientific notation numbers and compare their exponents and mantissas separately to arrive at the comparison with the threshold.

```
awk -F ',' -v threshold=2.23E-308 '
BEGIN {
  split(threshold, t, /[Ee]/)
   pwrThreshold = t[2]
   numThreshold = t[1]
}
NR>1 {
  num = $8 ~ /[Ee]/ ? $8   \
      : sprintf("%0.6E", $8)
  split(num, a, /[Ee]/)
  pwr = a[2]
  num = a[1]
  gr8 = pwr > pwrThreshold ? 1 \
      : pwr < pwrThreshold ? 0 \
      : num > numThreshold ? 1 \
      : 0;
}
gr8||NR==1
' file.csv
```

---

Results:-

```
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
2:31467079_G_A,rs2295471,2,31467079,G,A,-0.0830949,8.60
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `perl` rather than `awk`:

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print if ($F[7] >= 2.23E-308 || $. == 1)' input.csv 
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

Notes:

1. perl arrays start from 0, not 1, so `$F[7]` is the eighth field of each input line (equivalent to `$8` in awk).
2. `$.` is the input line number, equivalent to `NR` in awk.
3. if you also need to do arbitrary-precision floating point calculations in the script, you should probably look at perl's [Big::Float](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat) module.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'put get; for lines() {.put if .split(",").[7] >= 2.23e-308};'
```

Above is an answer which `get`s the header line and `put`s (prints) it, then--with the `for lines()` call--works on the remainder of the file linewise:

- `split`ting each succesive line on commas,
- pulling out the zero-indexed `7`th field, and
- performing numeric comparison in order to see which lines satisfy the `if` conditional.

Sample Input:

```
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value           
7:106350628_G_A,rs6977865,7,106350628,G,A,-0.0808873,8.6E-309
7:106353698_T_C,rs74804152,7,106353698,T,C,-0.0808701,9.3E-309
20:57674276_T_A,rs6026699,20,57674276,T,A,-0.0945835,6.0E-314
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
2:31467079_G_A,rs2295471,2,31467079,G,A,-0.0830949,8.6E-320
```

Sample Output:

```
VARIANT,SNP,chr,pos,A1,A2,BETA,P_value           
1:10177_A_AC,rs367896724,1,10177,A,AC,0.000264372,9.3E-01
1:10642_G_A,rs558604819,1,10642,G,A,0.0425225,7.0E-01
```

There are a few other ways obtain the desired result in Raku. Below is code that is similar to the Perl(5) solution posted by @cas (note, the `||` alternation elements are in reverse order, to avoid a `Cannot convert string to number` error):

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i=0; ++$i; .put if ( $i == 1 || .split(",").[7] >= 2.23e-308 );'
```

Another way uses Raku's `lines` and `grep` routines:

```perl
raku -e 'put get; .put for lines.grep( {.split(",").[7] >= 2.23E-308} );'
```

Finally, should you want a "bare bones" inplementation, delete the header manually and run the code below: you'll get back your desired data rows (presumably you can add the header back manually):

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .split(",").[7] >= 2.23e-308;'
```

https://raku.org